# Spring Boot : Heroku errors after successful deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, thymeleaf

I am struggling with this issue for a couple of days and couldn't find anything on SO and the description of error codes on heroku is to vague for me to figure out anything.I have created a basic app with no db integration, with spring framework , thymeleaf and spring mail.I have no spring security.After successfully deploying it to heroku i try to start the application server and this is what i get in the heroku logs.The app works fine on localhost with no issue.

```
2020-08-05T08:03:50.144941+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-05 08:03:50.144  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-05T08:03:50.458342+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-05 08:03:50.458  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-05T08:03:50.471638+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-05 08:03:50.471  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.e.P.MyWebWebsiteApplication        : Started MyWebWebsiteApplication in 2.688 seconds (JVM running for 3.226)
2020-08-05T08:04:53.993643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=myweb01.herokuapp.com request_id=0fb69db1-5c01-412e-b01f-451a8a2b7ad8 fwd="86.124.21.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-05T08:05:16.255402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2020-08-05T08:05:16.271979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-08-05T08:05:16.349020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-08-05T08:05:16.389343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-05T08:05:16.392175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-05T08:05:23.662195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/MyWebWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=25487 $JAR_OPTS`
2020-08-05T08:05:25.791836+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-08-05T08:05:25.796964+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

This is my procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/MyWebWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS
```

reading the logs and finding this here  `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080` i suppose could be an issue? i mean tomcat is trying to start on localhost port instead of heroku port?If this is the case how can i fix it? if this is not the case , what could be the issue ?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications#webapp-runner-tomcat
for Tomcat try adding `--port $PORT`

Comment: i have read that article but i am kinda confused, where do i have to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h20-app-boot-timeout) error code H20 means

> The router will enqueue requests for 75 seconds while waiting for
> starting processes to reach an “up” state. If after 75 seconds, no web
> dynos have reached an “up” state, the router logs H20 and serves a
> standard error page

If your application requires more time to boot, you may use the [boot timeout tool](https://tools.heroku.support/limits/boot_timeout) to increase the limit. However, in general, slow boot times will make it harder to deploy your application and will make recovery from dyno failures slower, so this should be considered a temporary solution

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications#spring-boot `-Dserver.port=$PORT` that's fine.

Comment: i have set boot time to 120 s from 90 s but the issue remains the same

Comment: If you run the app locally..how much time it takes to start? Are you doing anything on startup?

Comment: if i run app on localhost it take 4 seconds to load.I don't think i do anything on startup?Could you be more explicit on that please?

Comment: you said you have spring mail..what is being done as part of that? Are you connecting to outside IP or something?

Comment: well i am using spring mail for a contact form i am using in the view, so that the user can send me an email.Not sure how to respond on the IP question since this is the first time i did this.

Comment: thing is the first error that appears as soon as i run the app from heroku, is that ```my app did not send any data ``` and then when i check in the console i see what i have written in the OP , what do you think about this?

Comment: I though you are connecting to an external mail server which might be failing

Answer (score 0):

Try to set boot timeout to 120 seconds - some SpringBoot apps take some time to boot. The request can be done as shown here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/364

Also, the health check process is based on HTTP requests, so be sure that your app is served through normal Web ports (80, 8080, 443).

Comment: ok , i have set the timeout to 120 seconds but same issue persist.How can i make sure my app is server through normal web ports?

Comment: Well, normally a SpringBoot app is served through port 8080, and then Heroku exposes the 8080 to 80 and 443 if SSL is on. What happens if you leave the standard SpringBoot behaviour by removing '-Dserver.port=25487'?

Comment: i have modified procfile to this ```web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/MyWebWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $JAR_OPTS``` and i have same issue , i have also tried with this ```web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/MyWebWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=25487 $JAR_OPTS ```same issue. What could cause this?what am i missing ?